# Django: "wsgi_dev.py is not execitable"

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm brand-new to Django and sort-of new to ython.  I'm trying to set up Django on my windows-based machine.  I'm using Apache as the web server.  I am using a local wsgi_dev.py instead of the generated wsgi.py.  I'm getting the following errors:

```
[Fri Aug 04 14:58:12.267407 2017] [win32:error] [pid 3604:tid 1272] [client 127.0.0.1:52207] AH02102: C:/wamp/www/circuits/circuits/circuits_database/wsgi_dev.py is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line
[Fri Aug 04 14:58:12.267407 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3604:tid 1272] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 127.0.0.1:52207] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/wamp/www/circuits/circuits/circuits_database/wsgi_dev.py
[Fri Aug 04 14:58:12.308435 2017] [win32:error] [pid 3604:tid 1268] [client 127.0.0.1:52208] AH02102: C:/wamp/www/circuits/circuits/circuits_database/wsgi_dev.py is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line, referer: http://circuits-dev.local/circuits/circuits
[Fri Aug 04 14:58:12.308435 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3604:tid 1268] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 127.0.0.1:52208] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/wamp/www/circuits/circuits/circuits_database/wsgi_dev.py, referer: http://circuits-dev.local/circuits/circuits
```

I have the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

And then further down:

```
WSGIPythonPath "c:/wamp/www/py3DjangoVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/wamp/www/py3djangovenv"

<VirtualHost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/%0"
ServerName circuits-dev.local

SetEnv DB_NAME circuits

WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/wamp/www/<myapp>/<myapp>/<appname>/wsgi_dev.py"

Alias /static/ "c:/wamp/www/<myapp>/<myapp>/static/"

#C:\wamp\www\<myapp>\<myapp>\<appname>  
<Directory C:/wamp/www/<myapp>/<myapp>/<appname>>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
<Directory C:/wamp/www/<myapp>/<myapp>/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?  I'm stumped.  Thanks.

Comment: Why did you add that cgi handler?

Comment: (Also, why aren't you using the provided wsgi.py, and why are you using Apache in dev anyway instead of the built in dev server?)

Comment: Not sure why I added the cgi-handler;  I probably just assumed it was necessary.  Anyways, I removed it and things magically started to work.  As for why we're using Apache, we use it in prod and want to keep the configurations & environment identical across dev, test, stage, and prod.  Thanks!